# Creating a custom Date object from Calendar?

Tags: java, date, timer, calendar, simpledateformat

I need to create a custom Date object. I get a user input in 24 hr format like hh:mm i.e. 17:49 hrs.
I want to set the hours and minutes as 17 and 49 respectively keeping other details like month , year , day as per the current time.For e.g if today is Dec 16,2014 and the time is 16:00 hrs , then i want a date object as Dec 16,2014 with time as 17:49 hrs. I know i can do this using deprecated apis , however i do not want to use them.I need the date object because i need to pass it to a java timer as java timer does not support any calendar object.

The user input comes as a string and i can parse that string using `new SimpleDateFormat(HH:mm)` contructor.
I tried using the Calendar.set apis but had no success.

Could some one give some direction on how to proceed.

PS. Sorry , i can't use Joda time :)

Comment: Why would you be willing to risk creating a custom date object, yet unwilling to use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)? With Joda-Time, you could use a single line of well-tested and well-worn code: `Date date = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ).withTime( 17, 49, 0, 0 ).toDate();`

Comment: @Basil Bourque.. Joda time was my first preference. However I don't have the privilege to use  it. We work on a product and use of any third party api is discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works fine , however i don't want to use any deprecated apis.

```
...
...
String timeInterval = "18:01";
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(timeInterval);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, date.getHours());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, date.getMinutes());
date = calendar.getTime();

System.out.println(date);
...
...
```

Comment: i edited my answer with a possible fix, but it feels like going around in circle... maybe splitting the input string in two is the better option. you decide.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Since `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` are deprecated and have been replaced with `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` and `Calendar.MINUTE` respectively, you could use an intermediary calendar object or set the `YEAR` and `DAY` to current values.

---

**There is a problem though, if you input next day hour like 24:01 it won't move to the next day. The previous answer, with splitting of string did the overflowing correctly.**

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    final String timeInterval = "12:01";
    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(timeInterval);
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); //calendar object with current date
    calendar.setTime(date); //set date with day january 1 1970, this is because you parsed only the time part, the date objects assumes you start from it's lowest value, try a System.out.println(date) before this to see.
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE,Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH))
    date = calendar.getTime();
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

---

You can use `Calendar` to set the time, then extract the date with `.getTime()` method, which returns a `java.util.Date`

The idea is to split your string into two parts based on the separator `:`.

Then simply initialize the calendar and set the hour and minutes with those values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    final String userInput = "17:49";
    final String[] timeParts=userInput.split(":");
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance(); //current moment calendar
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(timeParts[0]));
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(timeParts[1]));
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0); //if you don't care about seconds
    final Date myDate=cal.getTime(); //assign the date object you need from calendar
    //use myDate object anyway you want ...
    System.out.println(myDate);
}
```

Comment: @MihalC Thanks for the answer.I have already implemented this as you have suggested above.However i'm looking to implement this using available Calendar or Date apis. I'll go ahead with the current implementation in case i don't get a better answer. Thanks again !

Comment: @bluelurker i don't quite understand what you mean by available Calendar or Date apis. This answer uses the built in Calendar and Date classes, which come with the jdk. There are no external libs used.

Comment: @MihalC  It should have clicked to me before. It seems a good answer.Thanks a ton man.

Comment: @bluelurker you can remove the tmp calendar as well, just use one, i will edit answer. but please take care of the overflowing hour bug this answer can produce (i wrote in answer). When using the split string version, the overflowing is done correctly

Comment: @MilhalC i have already added a validated for hh:mm , So this won't be an issue.